# How to sort elements of pairs inside vector?

Tags: c++, sorting, std-pair

i have a pair of int and string inside a vector, how to sort them first on basis of int and if int value is duplicate then sort according to lexicographical manner of string.

```
vector< pair<int, string> > v;
```

Comment: [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).  no need for anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

`std::pair` is lexicographically compared.

On the other hand if you want to sort them with respect the second element of the `std::pair` then you would have to defind a custom comparator in the following manner:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::pair<int, std::string> const &p1,
                                 std::pair<int, std::string> const &p2) { 
                                   return (p1.second == p2.second)?
                                             p1.first < p2.first  :
                                             p1.second < p2.second;
                              });
```

Comment: if vector has these elements: nitin 85, akash 99, bhanu 85, i want to sort such that vector will now have akash 99,bhanu 85,nitin 85

Comment: the answer you provided will give following output: bhanu 85, nitin 85, akash 99 but  want opposite of this.

Comment: @Ni3_k - So pass in a Compare predicate to perform your custom sort.

Comment: @Ni3_k Then you would have `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>` and not  `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>` as the OP says.

Comment: i have std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>

Comment: @erip Why not just use `std::greater`?

Comment: @Ni3_k _i want to sort such that vector will now have akash 99,bhanu 85,nitin 85_ that's what mine does...?

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't know how to use it with a `std::pair`. :) Just `std::greater<std::pair<T, U>>()`?

Comment: @erip All you need to do is specify the type in this case since it has the correct built in operators.  http://ideone.com/0NjOha

Comment: what i did was when storing int and string i multiplied int value with -1 and then sorted in ascending order and then displayed it again multiplying with -1

Answer (score 0):

what i did was to store int value multiplied with -1 and then sorted it in ascending order and then again multiplied to -1 to the stored int value to restore int values. doing this made the vector of pairs arranged as needed.